# Restart multiple CSS3 animations

Tags: css

If you have comma-separated values to declare multiple CSS3 animations, how can you restart the whole animation itself? First run `slideUp`, then run `fadeOut` (made possible with the `animation-delay` property), then restart all that.

```
.mySelector {
   myAnimation: 
     -webkit-animation:  slideUp 0.5s ease-in-out 0 1 normal forwards running, 
                         fadeOut 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 normal forwards running;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by removing and adding the element again:

```
var elm = document.querySelector(".mySelector");
var newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
```

https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add to animation property:

```
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

for full reference [check the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: No, that will restart the first animation immediately after it is executed.

Comment: now I understand that's because you have 2 animations not 1... you could fix that setting the animations with same time length